# How do I avoid my video input being distorted?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, image, video, distort

I'm trying to edit some video from a fairly old camera. The video is in 1440x1080 resolution, so my file is set up with those dimensions. However, when I import my video with an Image node, it is squished horizontally, until it's nearly a square.

To fix this, I have to import a still frame (or any other image that's 1440x1080) and put it behind using an Alpha Over node, as well as scaling the video input to ~1.33 times its width. Is there a saner way to fix this issue?

**Screenshot of my Current Fix:**

[image: Screenshot of Node Editor]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many older cameras use rectangular pixels in their CCDs, and will produce distorted images when imported into software using square pixels.
You should be able to correct your rendered output by adjusting the Aspect Ratio values (x=1.33 in your case) in the Render Tab -> Dimensions Panel.
[image]

Comment: That seems to fix it for the final render result, so thank you! It doesn't fix it for the backdrop / preview, though. Is there any way I can tweak the appearance in there and in the movie clip editor?